# Proving that $(A_1 \cdots A_m)^{-1} = A_m^{-1} \cdots A_1^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question was assigned in my linear algebra class.  I understand invertable matrices pretty well, but am unclear on how to begin and prove the following statement:

> Prove that for $A_1, \ldots , A_m$ invertible matrices
>   $(A_1 \cdots A_m)^{-1} = A_m^{-1} \cdots A_1^{-1}$.

Comment: What is the definition of the inverse of a matrix $M$?

Comment: We have inverse reversal property for it

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $A^{-1} = B$ if you show that $AB= I$.

In particular, you're done with your proof if you can show

$$\left(A_1A_2A_3\cdots A_m\right)\left(A_m^{-1}A_{m-1}^{-1}\cdots A_2^{-1}A_1^{-1}\right)=I$$

Use the fact that matrix multiplication is associative. Use the fact that $A_kA_k^{-1}=I$ for each $k$. Use the fact that $AI=A$ for all square matrices $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by induction can work nicely.

**Hint:** Take $m = 2$ as your base case.  Then note that
$$
(A_1 \cdots A_m)^{-1} = 
[(A_1 \cdots A_{m-1})A_m]^{-1}
$$